# MySQL - Missing records after importing data from CSV

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import, missing-data

I'm using the following query to import data into an empty table from a CSV file:
But for some reason, there is a difference of ~13,000 records (missing from database after loading)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/20230727_Shipments.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE hos_asn_details_20230726 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\b'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Rows in CSV file: 1,419,456
Rows in DB query: 1,406,783
Difference: 12,675

Any idea/hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

I tried checking if it's a duplicate issue, but that shouldn't be the case since it should import all the records regardless of potential repetition.

Comment: 1. Check whether there are any errors in the log when importing.
2. Is there any duplicate data in csv file (especially columns with primary key or unique index)?

Comment: 'I tried checking if it's a duplicate issue, but that shouldn't be the case since it should import all the records regardless of potential repetition.' - not true since you are using replace...

Comment: @dogsCute 
1. No errors in the logs

Comment: You could try Notepad++ and the CSV Lint plug-in to check for any errors in the csv data https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/ or you can also use the plugin to just convert the csv data to SQL `INSERT` statements